# Grunt changing multiple times

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs

I have a grunt file that watches for changes on app.css. The watch appears to be processing the file multiple times upon change of app.css. Checked the file and the output is correct.

#### Grunt File

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    "use strict";
    grunt.initConfig({
        //concat: {
        //  css: {
        //    src: ['app/css/*.css'],
        //    dest: 'app/css/app.min.css'
        //  }
        //},
        cssmin: {
            minify: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'app/css/',
                src: ['*.css', '!*.min.css'],
                dest: 'app/css/',
                ext: '.min.css'
            }
        },
        watch: {
            //js: {
            //  files: ['app/js/**/*.js'],
            //  tasks: ['concat']
            //},
            css: {
                files: ['app/css/*.css'],
                tasks: ['cssmin']
            }
        }
    });

    //grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat'); // Load concat
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');    // Load watch
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');   // Load CSS min
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);     // Load default task
};
```

Comment: It is because the first pass modifies the `app.css` file which creates `app.min.css` -- but your watcher is looking for modifications to ANY CSS files (including the newly-created `app.min.css`)?

Comment: Thanks, knew it would be something simple :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the first pass modifies the `app.css` file which creates `app.min.css` -- but your watcher is looking for modifications to ANY CSS files (including the newly-created `app.min.css`).

You can either ignore `*.min.css` in your watcher config, or just output the minified CSS to a folder you're not watching.